# How to use Composite Trapezoidal Rule for this particular problem

Tags: numerical-methods

The original ODE I had was $4f‴+ff″+2(f′)²=0$ with $f(0)=α,f′(0)=β$

Now I want to use Composite Trapezoidal Rule for this integral :
$$                        
                       ∫(f-α)(f′)²dη = 1    \qquad        \text{from}\,\, 0 \,\,\text{to}\,\, ∞
$$
Please help me to find the value of $α$.
It would be very nice if anyone help me with the MATLAB code specially how to define the function for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the trapezoidal method, when you can package all into the ODE solver? Use

```
[ f0', f1', f2', g', h' ] = [ f1, f2, -0.25*(f0*f2+2f1^2), f1^2, f*f1^2 ]
```

and solve for boundary conditions

```
f0(0)=a, f1(0)=b, f2(0)=c, g(0)=0, h(0)=0
```

and at the other end the asymptotic conditions and equations

```
f1(N)=0, f2(N)=0, a*g(N)-h(N)=0
```

for some large upper interval end `N`.

Comment: But i don't know the value of a and b.
is this problem solvable through trapezoidal method ?

Comment: That is why you solve a boundary value problem. You have 3 unknown at time $0$ that get propagated to time $N$ and 3 equations to satisfy at time $N$. So you have to solve a non-linear 3×3 system, where the computation of the function values includes the integration of the ODE.